# If one root of an equation is treble the other, prove the following equation.

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

I require some assistance with regards to the below, many thanks in advance! :)

If one root of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is treble the other, prove that $3b^2-16ac=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Call one root $p$, then the other one is $3p$ and $ax^2+bx+c$ can be factored as $a(x-p)(x-3p)$. Now expand and compare (what is $b$, what is $c$?), then compute $3b^2-16ac$.

Alternatively, but this comes down to the same, the sum and product of the roots are respectively:
$$\mbox{sum } = -\frac{b}{a} = 4p \quad \mbox{and} \quad \mbox{product} = \frac{c}{a} = 3p^2$$

Comment: We should eliminate the foreign variable $p$

Answer (score 0):

$\ ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two roots $\ x_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\ x_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

you know from the statement of the problem that 
$\ x_1=3x_2$
so
$\ \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=3\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

after some trivial operations you will get what you need

Comment: How do you know it's not the other way round? i.e. in your notation that $x_2 = 3x_1$? And the operations may be trivial, but that does not make them any less tedious: the hint in the other answer is a much better way to go.

Comment: I never said that my way is better :)

Comment: I know :-) - I just wanted to steer the OP in the more productive direction.